# Why vector::insert exception safety

Tags: c++, vector

Previously I asked a question about what was the exception safety of `vector::insert` (for reference, the answer was that it has basic guarantee). I also asked about self-referencing iterators (e.g. `vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end())` and it seems that they are banned.

It seems that for any type with nothrow move construction, it would be more than possible to permit the strong guarantee and allow self-referencing iterators to be passed in. Even for types without nothrow move construction, you could still offer the basic guarantee whilst permitting self-referencing iterators. So I'm curious why these restrictions.

Why are these restrictions (only basic exception safety, no self-referencing iterators) in place?

Comment: Who banned the first insertion and how? Surely that would give an indication of where the limitation comes from?

Comment: My bad. They are indeed supposed to be the same vector.

Comment: I think this question is poorly phrased. What is the first paragraph about? Are you asking about exceptions, or about iterator invalidation? What exactly is your current state of understanding, and what is the question? (I still think we should have a "grep for question mark" pre-submit check on new questions...)

Comment: I want to know why the current restrictions (only basic guarantee, no self-referencing iterators) are that way.

Comment: I still don't understand. The operation isn't even *valid* on account of the sequence container requirements, so exception guarantees don't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Doesn't this also require nothrow move assignment (as well as nothrow move construction)? -- Btw, are you referring to moving the elements back in case of an exception to provide the strong guarantee?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, but *why* is it UB? And *why* would it not have a strong guarantee if the arguments came from some other vector?

Comment: @Puppy: Because the standard says so - the input range may not come from within the container itself. Presumably because it would put a lot more  burden on the implementer with very little gain. What becomes of this the question if we remove the issue of taking the range from the same container?

Comment: Right, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't put extra burden on the implementer. (Also, there's still the question of only basic exception safety).